# What is the proper way to handle the pixel buffer returned by GetDIBits()?

Tags: c, winapi, sdl, gdi

I have been trying to make a SDL program that has the capability of taking a screenshot of the entire screen, and in this case, displaying a live feed of my whole monitor screen. I have succeeded to the extent that I have been able to retrieve a image using GDI functions, but I have no idea how to properly handle the data output in my buffer after the GetDIBits() function returns. My image so far has been way off the expected output. The colors are messed up in all the formats I've currently tried which has been most of the 32-bit and 24-bit pixel formats available for SDL textures. My win32 code might also have a bug, I'm not completely sure since the image displayed is incorrect.

Here is how I get a screenshot :

```
void WINAPI get_screenshot( app_data * app )
{
    HDC desktop = GetDC( NULL );
    int width = GetDeviceCaps( desktop, HORZRES );
    int height = GetDeviceCaps( desktop, VERTRES );
    HDC desktop_copy = CreateCompatibleDC( 0 );

    HGDIOBJ old = NULL;
    HBITMAP screenshot = CreateCompatibleBitmap( desktop_copy, app->viewport.w, app->viewport.h );

    BITMAPINFOHEADER screenshot_header = { 0 };
    screenshot_header.biSize = sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER );
    screenshot_header.biWidth = app->viewport.w;
    screenshot_header.biHeight = -app->viewport.h;
    screenshot_header.biPlanes = 1;
    screenshot_header.biBitCount = 32;
    screenshot_header.biCompression = BI_RGB;


    if ( !screenshot )
    {
        ReleaseDC( NULL, desktop );
        DeleteDC( desktop_copy );
        DeleteObject( screenshot );
        free_app_data( app );
        win_error( "Creating Bitmap", true );
    }

    SetStretchBltMode( desktop_copy, HALFTONE );
    SetBrushOrgEx( desktop_copy, 0, 0, NULL );
    old = SelectObject( desktop_copy, screenshot );

    if ( !StretchBlt( desktop_copy, 0, 0, app->viewport.w, app->viewport.h, desktop, 0, 0, width, height, SRCCOPY ) )
    {
        ReleaseDC( NULL, desktop );
        DeleteDC( desktop_copy );
        DeleteObject( screenshot );
        free_app_data( app );
        win_error( "Stretching Screenshot to Window Size", true );
    }

    if ( !GetDIBits( desktop_copy, screenshot, 0, app->viewport.h, app->pixels, ( BITMAPINFO * )&screenshot_header, DIB_RGB_COLORS ) )
    {
        ReleaseDC( NULL, desktop );
        DeleteDC( desktop_copy );
        DeleteObject( screenshot );
        free_app_data( app );
        win_error( "Getting Window RGB Values", true );
    }

    SelectObject( desktop_copy, old );

    DeleteObject( screenshot );
    ReleaseDC( NULL, desktop );
    DeleteDC( desktop_copy );

    return;
}
```

I feel most of the code that calls my DLL functions is self explanatory or isn't critical for this post, but I'll be happy to provide pseudo code or pure win32 API code if necessary.

The code that creates the SDL texture and buffer is :

```
    app->frame = SDL_CreateTexture(
                                   app->renderer,
                                   SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888,
                                   SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
                                   app->viewport.w,
                                   app->viewport.h
                                  );

    if ( !app->frame )
    {
        free_app_data( app );
        SDL_errorexit( "Creating texture", 1, TRUE );
    }

    app->pixels = ( Uint32 * )create_array( NULL, ( app->viewport.w * app->viewport.h ), sizeof( Uint32 ), zero_array );

    if ( !app->pixels )
    {
        free_app_data( app );
        std_error( "Creating pixel buffer", TRUE );
    }
```

Again, I'm using my DLL function create_array() in this case, but I think you should be able to tell what it does.

The resulting image is this :

[image: The image output from my program]
Feel free to add better methods or pure SDL methods of doing this. I have tried GetPixel(), and it returns correct values. It has a high overhead for multiple calls though.

Comment: It looks like the potential problem is where you create the compatible bitmap. The bitmap should be created the exact size of the display, not the size of your SDL bitmap. You NEVER want to let GDI scale down a bitmap because you'll get results like you see.

Comment: Why use sdl when you are trying to get a simple screenshot. Using just winapi you can accomplish the same result with minimum coding.

Comment: @BitBank I changed it but it didn't completely fix it, just made the image slightly better.

Comment: @Valter Yes, I'm trying to get a simple screenshot, but I'm also updating it to GPU memory in a loop on my GUI screen while handling events. While I've done pure win32 API GUIs before, the SDL API is much simpler, and probably faster than the code I would normally create in this instance. It can also be easily reused or changed.

Comment: I've written code to do the same thing and the differences I see are that I used CreateDIBSection() with the DC of the screen, not the memory DC. I also created a BITMAPINFOHEADER with BI_BITFIELDS and set up the bit fields to match the bit depth of the display. A bitblt into the DIBSection will immediately give you the pixel data as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The code for capturing and drawing the screen to your form:

```
HDC hdcScreen, hdcForm;

hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
hdcForm = GetWindowDC(hwnd); //hwnd is form handle

StretchBlt(hdcForm, 0, 0, formW, formH, hdcScreen , 0, 0, screenW, screenH, SRCCOPY );

ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcForm);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
```

Its that simple.

valter